# Swift how to use property animator with pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

So I have a `UIView` with a `PanGestureRecognizer` attached that allows me to move the view up and down. As I move the view up, I want to **decrease my button's alpha** and when I **move the view down I want to increase it back to normal**.

I have tried to animate the button separately when it snaps into a position but this then breaks my `PropertyAnimator`.

My current implementation works find, **provided that my finger is on the view** as this returns the `.changed` state from the recogniser. But I also have implementation that snaps the view into position when the view is release at a certain point along the **y axis**. The problem is that it doesn't hit the .changed state and therefore change my `hideAnimator.fractionComplete` leaving the button half way through its animation.

**Initialise property animator method**

```
func initPropertyAnimator() {

    hideAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.18, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.requestButton.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

**Recogniser states in** `panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)`

```
let currentY = self.frame.minY

switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        print("Began")

    case .changed:

        // Property animator
        let offset: CGFloat = window!.frame.height-194
        let percentage: CGFloat = (offset-currentY)/100
        print(percentage)
        hideAnimator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(percentage)

    case .ended:
        // Snap back below 80 (y)
        if currentY < 80 || currentY > 80 && currentY < halfWayPoint
        {
            self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
                    self.requestButton.alpha = 0
                    self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            }, completion: { (true) in

            })
        }

        // Snap back above partial (y)
        if currentY > partialY || currentY < partialY && currentY > halfWayPoint
        {
            self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: partialY, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
                    self.requestButton.alpha = 1
                    self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            }, completion: { (true) in

            })
        }
```

Comment: I have actually implemented a UIView.animate call that snaps the view with the pan gesture into place depending on it's place on the screen. But this doesn't carry on updating the UIView's Y position.

Comment: OK so now you've totally changed what you claim your code is. I do hope this is the truth this time. :) So now perhaps I'm just being dense but I don't get what you say is wrong about what that code does or doesn't do...

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it too well, my problem is, if I scroll my UIView half way, and then let go for it to snap back into position, it only half animates because I let go half way through and the propertyAnimator stops receiving `fractionComplete` for the y position

Comment: Right, well, in your `.ended` implementation you have stopped talking to the property animator. If you want it to do anything more at this point, you have to tell it what you want it to do. I can't tell you how to do that because I'm unclear on what you _do_ want it to do. But it is easy to say to an animator "hurry back to the starting place", for example. Indeed, the fact that this is easy to say is one of the great benefits of using a view property animator in the first place.

Comment: Your code, however, seems to just say `self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)`, which effectively just drops everything and walks away. If that isn't what you wanted to do, don't do that.

Comment: Okay I fiddled about and implemented the 'initPropertyAnimator' code to the .began which now works after removing the .stopAnimation also. However, trying to get it to animate back to its starting position isn't working, I am enabling `isReversed` correctly but doesn't want to have any of it. What method is best to animate its return to starting position? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170041/discussion-between-niall-kiddle-and-matt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a **boolean** to check whether or not the view is currently expanded and then depending on **true or false** I load the corresponding animations. I know this is not the best way of doing things as you are able to return the animation to its original place without having to write so much code. Regardless, it works, so I'll roll with it.

By the way, I am very much open to anyone who can help refine this code, it definitely is in need of some TLC.

Here is my **entire method** that handles my `panGestureRecogniser`

```
// MARK: - Pan gesture

@objc func panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
    let currentY = self.frame.minY
    let partialY = (window?.frame.height)!-194
    let halfWayPoint = ((window?.frame.height)!/2)-40

    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: currentY + translation.y, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        print("Began")

        if isExpanded
        {
            animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.18, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
                self.requestButton.alpha = 1
                self.houseView.alpha = 0
                self.officeView.alpha = 0
                self.gardenView.alpha = 0
                self.carView.alpha = 0
                self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            })
            self.animator?.isReversed = true
        }
        else
        {
            animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.18, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
                self.requestButton.alpha = 0
                self.houseView.alpha = 1
                self.officeView.alpha = 1
                self.gardenView.alpha = 1
                self.carView.alpha = 1
                self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            })
            self.animator?.isReversed = false
        }

        animator?.startAnimation()
        animator?.pauseAnimation()

    case .changed:

        // Property animator
        let offset: CGFloat = window!.frame.height-194
        let fraction: CGFloat = (offset-currentY)/4
        let percentage = fraction/100
        print(percentage)
        animator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(percentage)

        // Prevent scrolling up past y:0
        if currentY <= 0
        {
            self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        }

    case .ended:

        // Snap to 80 (y) (expanded)
        if currentY < 80 || currentY > 80 && currentY < halfWayPoint
        {
            self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.62, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
                    self.requestButton.alpha = 0
                    self.houseView.alpha = 1
                    self.officeView.alpha = 1
                    self.gardenView.alpha = 1
                    self.carView.alpha = 1
                    self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            }, completion: { (true) in
                self.isExpanded = true
            })
        }

        // Snap back to partial (y) (original position)
        if currentY > partialY || currentY < partialY && currentY > halfWayPoint
        {
            self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.62, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: partialY, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
                    self.requestButton.alpha = 1
                    self.houseView.alpha = 0
                    self.officeView.alpha = 0
                    self.gardenView.alpha = 0
                    self.carView.alpha = 0
                    self.houseView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 87+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.officeView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 171+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.carView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 255+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
                    self.gardenView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 339+200, width: self.boxWidth, height: 68)
            }, completion: {(true) in
                self.isExpanded = false
            })
        }

    case .cancelled:
        print("Cancelled")

    case .failed:
        print("Failed")

    default:
        print("Default")
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this project: https://www.onswiftwings.com/posts/interactive-animations/